# /var/lib/mysql folder is not coming up after install

Tags: mysql, centos, var

I'm having some trouble with reinstalling MySQL, since i uninstalled it. I have been unable to install it again.

```
yum install mysql-server
yum install mysql
```

But what ever I do, the folder /var/lib/mysql is not having any files in it. When I do the command

```
mysql
```

I get this message: "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)"
I don't know what to do, what can I do to get the folder reappearing?

Comment: What version of MySQL ???

Comment: And, what version of CentOS ???

Answer (score 4):

/var/lib/mysql is populated when mysqld is first started. Installing a package with yum doesn't automatically start mysqld.

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
chkconfig mysqld on
```

If I'm all wrong about this and you already tried to start mysqld, post mysqld.log please.

Answer (score 0):

## OBSERVATION #1

MySQL is usually autostarted upon RPM installation. As of MySQL 5.5.8, that is no longer the case.

## OBSERVATION #2

When you run an RPM install, the service is called `/etc/init.d/mysql`. Since you ran a yum install, the service is called `/etc/init.d/mysqld`.

## SUGGESTION

Please run this:

```
MYSQL_SERVICE_NAME=`chkconfig --list | grep -i ^mysql | awk '{print $1}'`
echo ${MYSQL_SERVICE_NAME}
```

Then, try running

```
service ${MYSQL_SERVICE_NAME} start
```

and see if mysql starts up

Sorry if this seems like overkill. You will only need to do this once. Whatever `MYSQL_SERVICE_NAME` is, that's the service name you should always use.

Comment: Wow, overkill. :)